# DataSource and JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, in-memory-database

Hi I have a strange situation with my query to data base.
My DataBase - in-memory and when I make query using JdbcTemplate it's ok, but if I using DataSource, I taking an empty ResultSet. Who could explain to me what happen?

Example through the JdbcTemplate:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from t_history where process_instance_id = '92604760'");
```

Example through the DataSource:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("select * from t_history where process_instance_id = '92604760'");
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
    while (resultSet.next()){
      System.out.println("Have record");
    }
```

This both piece of code written one after another.

Comment: Could you try with the basic way as described here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html with the `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say what is DataBase which I using, it's H2 Database.

Comment: And there are described similar, isn't?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: It may not be relevant, but what is the data type of process_instance_id?  If it's not a varchar, you could try removing the single quotes around the value.